# How to alert for duplicate values of dynamically added input boxes ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have multiple `input` fields with different values. I can edit them but cannot be empty (if empty show an alert). When I am editing it to new values, if the new value matches with any of the other `input` values,an `alert` that *you cannot use this* is shown.This is working fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/0c0qep6y/18/).

But the functionality is not working for dynamically added(add button) `input`.

> How to apply the same functionality for dynamically added elements ?

**HTML**

```
<div id="inputstack">
<input type="text" class="selector" value="new">
<input type="text" class="selector" value="old">
<input type="text" class="selector" value="newest">
<input type="text" class="selector" value="oldest">
<input type="text" class="selector" value="older">
</div>

<input type="button" value="Add" id="addinput" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.selector').on('blur',function () {
    var current_value = $(this).val();
  $(this).attr('value',current_value);
console.log(current_value);
    if ($('.selector[value="' + current_value + '"]').not($(this)).length > 0 || current_value.length == 0 ) {
      $(this).focus();
        alert('You cannot use this');
    }
});
$('#addinput').click(function(){
$('#inputstack').append("<input type="text" class="selector" value="">");
});
```

Comment: bind an jquery each() function. dint forget to unbind() first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use event delegation mechanism as below to deal with dynamically added input boxes:

`$(document).on('blur','.selector',function () {`

Updated fiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/0c0qep6y/21/

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic added elements you need to add the listener to the parent as so

```
$('#inputstack').on('blur','.selector', function () {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think it can be helpful.**

```js
$("#addinput").click(function(){
  var obj = {};
  var i = 0;
  $(".selector").each(function(){
    if(this.value === "") {
      alert("value can't be empty");
    }else if(obj.hasOwnProperty(this.value)) {
      alert("there is a duplicate value " + this.value);
    } else {
      obj[this.value] = this.value;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inputstack">
<input type="text" class="selector" value="">
<input type="text" class="selector" value="old">
<input type="text" class="selector" value="newest">
<input type="text" class="selector" value="oldest">
<input type="text" class="selector" value="older">
</div>

<input type="button" value="Add" id="addinput" />
```